# storing the print value of a for loop with if else in a variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, list-comprehension

I need to store the print value of this code into a variable so that I can dump it into a text file.

```
for i, j, v in sorted(zip(m.row, m.col, m.data)):
            if doc_id == -1:
                print(str(j) + ':' + "{:.4f}".format(v), end=' ')
            else:
                if doc_id != i:
                    print()
                print(str(j) + ':' + "{:.4f}".format(v), end=' ')
            doc_id = i
```

I used list comprehension and appending it into a variable but didn't help.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with storing values in variables, you should look up a tutorial like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Additionally, the code in this question is from an answer to [a previous question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742105/converting-a-text-corpus-to-a-text-document-with-vocabulary-id-and-respective-tf). This site is not a coding service; please do some of your own work.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `print`, you ask the Python to pass the content to the `stdin` i.e print the content to the console. If you want to store it in variable, you need to remove the content from `print()` and store in variable. For example in your case as:

```
my_list = []
my_var = str(j) + ':' + "{:.4f}".format(v)
my_list.append(my_var)  # add variable to list

# Uncomment this if you also want to print the value
# print(my_var)
```